# document.ready() is not working

Tags: jquery

here i'm getting data from DB. its working in html file, but not working through individual .js file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.post("class.php",{getdata:'true'},
    function(result)
    {
        $('#class_incharge_id').html(result);
    });

    $.post('class.php',{check:'true'}, function(rslt)
    {
        $('#check').html(rslt);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have included jquery library ?

Comment: not working means what? What is the error in console ?

Comment: may be something is missed in giving ref to .js file

Comment: most likely cause is that jquery is loaded after your js. From the dev console you can see the order in which resources are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

May be cause of not working due to one of the following reason :

1. May be you have not included [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/)
2. May be you forget to include that individual .js file
3. Or may be you have include your js file before jquery library. `You have to include .js file after jQuery library.`

You will know what exactly causing error by checking your console for errors

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have included JQuery BEFORE the reference of your JS file where the code is written. As it was working before you seperated it into new JS file this seems to be the most likely cause.